# Magento: How show on frontend the Keyword attribute of product

Tags: magento, attributes, product

Not finding anything on google that solves this problem.
I'm trying to add keywords attribute after the description of the product.

Tried:

```
<?php echo $_product->getMetaKeyword() ?>

<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getMetaKeyword(), 'meta_keyword') ?>

< ?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('meta_keyword') ?>
```

I'm want add this on list.phtml
\app\design\frontend\default\mt_Bonasa\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the attribute managment and configure the

> meta_keyword

attribute to be "used in product listing". Then it will be joined to the collection and you can simply fetch it via:

```
$_product->getMetaKeyword()
```

Here a screenshot how its set out of the box - switch to "yes"

[image]

Comment: Tks. This is the solution!